# English word that means "a process that does not teach you anything"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, adjectives, terminology

I am looking for a word that means “a process that you keep doing, hoping that you will learn something useful, but which you actually never learn anything from”. I'm quite sure that there is an English word for that: I read it once, but I cannot now remember it.

As an example:

Imagine your fridge keeps breaking and you keep fixing it, but you never learn anything new about fridges or about fixing them, since the whole fridge fixing process is "____".

The word that I am looking for is more about the skills and knowledge that you learn (or not) when you carry out a process, rather than about the success of the process itself.

**Edit**
The process is as following:
The fridge gets broken, lets call this failure-A, you as a good maintainer don't just fix the problem you also go very deep to understand what caused the problem and how you can prevent it again. After learning that, you hope that its going to help you in fixing the next issues.

However, when the fridge fails with failure-B you try to apply all the steps you learned from your previous fixes, nothing works. So you learn new skills from failure-B.

Repeat the following for failure-C, D, E .... and so on.
This word would describe the whole fridge problem-fixing process.

Comment: How about _redundant_?

Comment: It's very similar to redundant, but with more focus on the learning process, it's tormenting me :S

Comment: "An exercise in futility"?

Comment: Sterile:  not productive of results, ideas, etc.; fruitless.

Comment: Einstein supposedly defined that as "insanity".

Comment: _Mindless_? Mac OS X's dictionary carries a few meanings, the last one being _* (of an activity) so simple or repetitive as to be performed automatically without thought or skill._

Comment: @ermanen, Oldbag, Josh61: In the example, it sounds pretty much like fixing the fridge is by no means redundant, futile, or fruitless; it seems to be very effective. One just does not learn anything new from it.

Comment: Maybe the asker means something like "stabbing in the dark" - one of those trial-and-error tasks based on guesswork where you try things until something works but you never understand *why* it worked?

Comment: @ermanen: No, I'm not the OP. I'm just another visitor who is interested in the answer to the question as it was asked. Indeed, maybe it was not the right fix (that has a permanent effect), but the OP wrote "your fridge keeps breaking and you keep fixing it", so it seems like the fix means at least a temporary change (or else the fridge would not *keep breaking*, it would simply remain broken).

Comment: @ermanen what O.R.Mapper said is correct, fixing the fridge is not a redundant task, fixing the fridge is indeed effective, as the fridge is back to operational mode after the fix. I will update the question with more details about the whole process.

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith: So he already knows how to fix and he did it before but he doesn't learn something new.

Comment: @ermanen you don't really know if you ever going to learn the whole fridge, how it works and how to fix it, and you keep trying to learn. However, this never makes you feel like you are getting closer to be a good fridge fixer person.

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith: Your update changed the whole question. I think we have more details but it is more confusing now :) So you learn something based an failures/fixes but you do not learn everything about fridges at once. Isn't it "iterative" or maybe "repetitive"? Also "trial and error" concept comes to mind.

Comment: I don't know. I just don't know. But the question as edited precisely and uncomfortably parallels my own experience with the refurbished laptop I'm using. And the word for that is, "exasperation!"

Comment: I personally think that you should scrap the "fixing fridge" example. Fixing something inherently teaches you how to deal with that again. Try another example, such as "attending a corporate motivation meeting". On topic, I personally find "futile" or "useless" to fit the bill

Comment: The title of the question does not match the body (Rev 4). The title says "a process that does not teach you anything", but the body says that you learn the root cause of Failure A and new skills when fixing Failure B. So, the question is self-contradictory. Therefore, I have voted to close it as "unclear what you are asking.

Comment: In light of your latest edits: _Uninformative_, _unedifying_, _uninstructive_, _unenlightening_?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first word that comes to mind is **[futile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/futile)**.

> fu·tile adjective \ˈfyü-təl, ˈfyü-ˌtī(-ə)l\
>   : having no result or effect : pointless or useless
>
> 1. : serving no useful purpose :  completely ineffective

I've often heard and used phrases like "This was an exercise in futility." You could also say "It is futile to work on that fridge. It will soon break again." Considering your recent edit you might say "Learning anything that is useful for the next problem is futile."

You might also consider some clever use of **[frivolous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frivolous)**. Nothing really great is coming to mind at the moment, but I'm sure you could think of something. Or just stick with futile.

Comment: +1 Or, use the more popular synonym "useless"

Answer (score 13):

It could well be that you're looking for *unedifying*.

From [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unedifying):

> **unedifying**  adjective
>
> not having the result of improving morality, **intellect**, etc
>   [bolding mine]

[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/edify) satisfyingly gives the appropriate sense for the base word here:

> **edify** Verb UK  (formal US)
>
> to improve someone's mind

Comment: Unedifying : (Especially of an event taking place in public) distasteful; unpleasant (ODO).

Comment: How can I use it in this sentence? 
the whole fridge-fixing process is unedifying
the whole fridge-fixing an unedifying process

Which one of the two sentences is preferred?

Comment: You'd put it more conversationally: 'Over the years, I have found the whole fridge-fixing process/thing distinctly/remarkably/surprisingly/disappointingly unedifying'.

Comment: Too chicken to post this as an answer, but I have heard [whack-a-mole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whac-A-Mole) used as a metaphor in similar circumstances.

Comment: Whack-a-mole is more like the adjectival form of 'painting the Forth Bridge'. Painters probably never expected it to be very edifying.

Answer (score 8):

Sisyphean.
It means to keep doing something but being unable to get anything fruitful.
 It comes from the story of Sisyphus, who was cursed to eternally roll a boulder up a hill. As soon as the he'd near the top, the boulder would roll down, and he would have to go to the bottom and roll it up again.
 It is work with no result.

Comment: It might be true and fit, but the normal connotation of sisyphean is more 'unending' than 'you learn nothing from it'.

Comment: It's also almost guaranteed to get you a blank look if you use it anywhere other than Eton... most English speakers aren't particularly current with Greek Mythology. They may have heard the story, but won't know the word.

Comment: @JonStory I would expect people to maybe know the word, but have never heard the story... since they "aren't particularly current with Greek Mythology".

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for **"fruitless"**? **"unproductive"**?

> fruitless (adj) - useless; unproductive; without results or success [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fruitless)
>
> producing no good results : not successful [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fruitless)

- They made a fruitless attempt to find a solution.
- It would be fruitless to continue.

another suggestion: uninstructive

Comment: Do you think "fruitless" describes the fridge example I used?

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith Sure, it's a fruitless, unproductive process. It doesn't fix your fridge and doesn't teach you anything either.

Comment: The word I am looking for is more concerned about the learning process that accompanies doing a repetitive process

Comment: Sure, it's on the tone of "Fixing the fridge over and over is a <<Blank>> process". The word that I am looking for is more about the skills and knowledge that you learn when you do a process, than it is about the product of the process itself.

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith discouraging? disheartening? unenlightening, uninstructive?

Comment: @Centaurus you _do_ fix your fridge short-term in this example. Sure, it breaks again later, but still isn't entirely fruitless.

Comment: +1 I couldn't think of much anything myself, but this is absolutely the perfect word. Learning all about the previous problems with the refrigerator has proven fruitless, as I haven't learned anything useful.

Answer (score 5):

*Mechanistic* describes the senseless performance of some activity, perhaps for a reason beyond one's actual comprehension.

> Imagine your fridge keeps breaking and you keep fixing it, but you never learn anything new about fridges or about fixing them, since the whole fridge fixing process is *only a mechanistic exercise*.

Comment: much better answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

...the whole fridge-fixing process is ***uninforming***.

Comment: Personally I think **uninformative** has a nicer ring to it.

Answer (score 2):

Would "stultifying" fit the bill for you?  It means causing you to lose enthusiasm and initiative, often because of tedium or excessive restrictions.

If the outcome was not what you desired, or even negative, you could describe the process as "counterproductive."

Answer (score 1):

The idiom *[spinning your wheels](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Spinning%20my%20wheels)* is often used to mean

> Like a car stuck in mud, to spin one's wheels is to try to make progress, but get nowhere. 
>   *I sat down to write my term paper, but after three hours realized I was just spinning my wheels.*

*Urban Dictionary*

It also sounds like *[déjà vu all over again](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deja_Vu_All_Over_Again)*, a redundantly recursive phrase often attributed to baseball legend Yogi Berra

*Wikipedia*

Answer (score 1):

**Mind-numbing**: (adjective) So extreme or intense as to prevent normal thought. [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/quotation-marks-American)

> "The process of repairing that refrigerator was so mind-numbing that I gave up and bought an Igloo cooler." Or, "Everybody knows that fixing refrigerators is a mind-numbingly tedious occupation, so I'm looking for career alternatives." And one final example should suffice, "Now I know why that Maytag repairman was always sleeping on the job! Repairing this refrigerator has been absolutely mind-numbing!"

Comment: Also can be used when something is particularly boring, in my experience at least. Perhaps the boredom kills off brain cells? ;P

Comment: @Iplodman I have *only* heard this term to mean boring and uninteresting, which is pretty much the opposite of extreme or intense.

Comment: Hey Now! @DCShannon - yes, taken in isolation, which is to say, out of context, that is how it would seem. Here though, extreme or intense would become *extremely* or *intensely*, acting as adverbs [or as *submodifiers*], wherein their intended sense becomes clear: To a very great degree; very: i.e., ‘Refrigerator repair is an extremely boring and uninteresting thing to do.’

Answer (score 0):

Could it be "intransferable"? Or possibly, "idiosyncratic"?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps "uneducational" would fit the bill.  However as this is not a "real" word in dictionary sense - uninstructive is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I believe **automatous** fits. It's the adjective form of "automaton".
Basically, you're acting like a machine, a robot. You get the job done, so in one sense you're effective, but you haven't expanded your creative problem-solving abilities.

Machines just blindly do exactly what you tell them to do - they have no understanding whatsoever about discovering the causes of things, nor can they recognize similarities and use this information to categorize problems and solutions.

A simpler word would be **robotic**.

Edit:

It's also possible you're looking for the word **rote**. You're fixing the fridge **by rote**, i.e. using a memorized procedure, which makes you unable to adjust for contingencies.

Comment: I don't like automatous: 1) Wiktionary (which is admittedly not a reliable source) lists it as obsolete, and more importantly 2) to me it implies there's an actual automaton involved.

Comment: @Kevin [This site](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/automatous) refers to Random House and to Collins English Dictionary - both list the adjective form and do not indicate it's obsolete. Google "define automatous" and it shows Merriam-Webster's definition to be "like, or suggestive of an automaton". So it does figuratively involve an automaton; e.g. the person doing the action. Similarly, you can call someone's motions robotic even though they aren't literally a robot.

Comment: I think the asker has made it clear with their edit that they're doing a *different* process each time, and therefore the previous attempts were not useful. This is essentially the opposite of a rote or robotic operation.

Answer (score 0):

jejune

early 17th century: from Latin jejunus ‘fasting, barren.’ The original sense was ‘without food,’ hence ‘not intellectually nourishing.’

1.
naive, simplistic, and superficial.
"their entirely predictable and usually jejune opinions"

2.
(of ideas or writings) dry and uninteresting.
"the poem seems to me rather jejune"

Answer (score 0):

work that is futile is also

**pointless**

work given to you that serves no purpose but to keep you occupied is

**busywork**

(U.S. English speaker)

Answer (score 0):

A wild-goose chase.

I was under the impression that the OP was looking for a noun (phrase).

Answer (score -1):

Never use a big word when a small word will suffice:

**boring**

Comment: In that case, maybe you meant 'work' instead of 'suffice'? ;)

Comment: @Iplodman: Different connotations.  I'd end up having to write "work well enough," or something similar, and that goes against *omit needless words*, which I consider more important.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Maybe *do* then? That has the same connotations. But as I said, good point!